# GTA V Installing Disc 2?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-online

I think my GTA disc is scratched and the game often restarts when I'm doing missions. It only happens during missions though. But i was thinking if I installed the play disc it wouldn't be spinning anymore and so the game wouldn't restart? However im not sure whether to do this, will It fix the problem and if if it doesn't can i uninstall it without losing my GTA Online progress??

Comment: It might help to specify what console you are on.

Comment: @MadMAxJr Xbox 360 obviously, the PS3 version of GTA 5 comes with 1 disk only.

Comment: Sorry ya XBOX. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Disc 2 and it will likely solve your problem, assuming the problem really is because of scratches on the disk.

The reason why Rockstar does not recommend installing both, is to boost loading speed; after all, loading half the game from HDD and the other half from disk is faster than loading *everything* from HDD.

In the case that installing disk 2 does *not* solve your problem, you can easily uninstall the game without losing any progress, since game data and save games are stored separately. In the case of GTA Online, [your character is saved on Rockstar's own servers](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200435267-Loss-of-GTA-Online-characters-cars-rank-items-apartments-money); however, it seems like [Rockstar servers don't like to remember people](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200344833-GTA-V-Character-lost-again-10-19-13-), but this is completely unrelated to installing/uninstalling the game on your console.

Comment: Thank You! But will my game become laggy and will there be texture popping in?

Comment: @JasonMurphy I don't think you'll experience worse lags than before, but there will almost certainly be stronger pop-ups (texture or objects) and you will have to wait quite a bit longer for the game to launch (around 20-50% longer). There are videos on youtube, where the difference are shown between installing 1 disk and both disk (along with PS3 with HDD or SSD)

Comment: OK What happens if i clear the cache?

Comment: @JasonMurphy [Here's one such video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0gPB0gdoOM). It's actually not too bad, all things considered.

Comment: @JasonMurphy Clearing the cache will get rid of game updates (not OS ones); this can help if the game suddenly broke after getting updated.

Comment: OK I think i'll try it. Hopefully it wont affect it too much and if it does ill uninstall it again i think. Thanks for all your help!